# Debian 11 dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init does not run the graphical menu

Tags: linux, debian, dpkg, cloud-init, debian-bullseye

I'm trying to run `dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init` on Debian 11
After I run the command, this shows up multiple times in the terminal:

```
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_TIME = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LC_PAPER = "bg_BG.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
```

and then nothing. I mean, it waits to write commands:

There is no configuration menu with options to choose from.
What should I do to make that menu show up so I can choose some stuff from there?

Answer (score 0):

Try `locale-gen`, this should generate locales if they don't exist.
Since the command also says, that LC_ALL and LANGUAGE aren't set, try with `export LANGUAGE=bg_BG.UTF-8` setting this variable.